# How to count zeroes with specific parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, parameters

I need to count an amount of zeroes. So far this code works:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (uFCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                nFCheckBox.Checked = false;
                pFCheckBox.Checked = false;
                decimal x = 0;
                if (Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x))
                {
                    var y = 1000000;
                    var answer = x * y;

                    displayLabel2.Text = (x.ToString().Replace(".", "").TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' }) + "00").Substring(0, 2);

                    string myString = answer.ToString();
                     // displayLabel5.Text = myString.Split('.')[0].Where(d => d == '0').Count().ToString();
                    displayLabel5.Text = myString.Split('.')[0].Where(d => d == '0').Count().ToString();

                }
```

It counts zero perfectly when I input numbers like 72, 47, 83, etc. But once I input numbers that end with a zero, it counts that zero. I need something that counts all zeroes after the first 2 digits. So 50 x 1,000,000 will be 50,000,000. but I dont need to count the first 2 digits, so I need it to output 6 in this scenario. 
More example:

```
1.0 x 1,000,000 = 1,000,000 - I only need to output 5 zeroes
0.10 x 1,000,000 = 100,000 - I only need to output 4 zeroes.
```

But I also need to maintain that if I input other numbers that dont "end" in zeroes it still counts properly. 
Examples:

```
72 x 1,000,000 = 72,000,000 - Needs to output 6
7.2 x 1,000,000 = 7,200,000 - Needs to output 5
.72 x 1,000,000 = 720,000 - Needs to output 4
```

Update:
I am now getting proper outputs when I use

```
decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2, str.Length - 2).Count( s => s == '0');
```

but now I get an error: "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"

Comment: What's the purpose of this code?  If you're just trying to format the number, I would do answer.ToString("#,#.###"); to get the format you want.

Comment: Convert to string & start counting "0" chars from character position 2 (ie skipping positions 0 & 1)??

Comment: The purpose is to out put the 2 main numbers then how many zeroes follow before the decimal. So if I input 0.001. 10 will be the first number, then how ever many zeroes follow will be the next, which should be 2. If that made any sense

Comment: What should the output be for 1.12, 11.22?

Comment: What if user input 5.0204 ??? then all these algorithms fails!

Comment: A user will never input something like that for what I am using it for.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly you just want it to output the number of zeros. To do this you would do the following:

```
var y = 1000000;
var answer = x * y;

string numString = answer.ToString();
char[] charArray = numString.ToCharArray();
int count = 0;
for(int i = 2; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
     if(charArray[i] == '0')
     {
          count++;
     }
}
string output = count.ToString();
```

Using this, output will be the string count of zeros after the first 2 digits.

Comment: This kind of works, any number before a decimal outputs correctly. But once I put in a number after a decimal like 0.12 or 0.1. Then it doesnt read it correctly.

Comment: Still not sure why this doesn't work with decimals - entering 0.1 would give a result of 100000, converting to string gives "100000" & counting from 2nd char gives 4. As would entering 0.12 => 120000 => "120000".

Comment: Justin, from reading your comment it seems like the only error would occur when the answer has a period in it. However the variable answer will never be a decimal until x is equal to 0.0000001, which is not one that you stated was having errors. Are you running x through the code im using at all or just the variable answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var y = 1000000;
var answer = x * y;
var str= answer.ToString();
var n = str.Substring(2, str.Length - 2).Count(s => s == '0');
```

Comment: I used this and it worked besides counting zeros properly once I use decimals like 1.5 and stuff. So I used: var n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2, str.Length - 2).Count( s => s == '0').ToString(); Which works but now it is creashing for some reason, saying that length needs to a specific location in a string